# R - Unexpected '{' even with matched brackets?

Tags: r, unexpected-token

If all of my brackets are matched, and (I think) I'm not using any misplaced characters, how does the 'unexpected '{' in ' {' error still pop up?

Here is the code:

```
listsarw<-function(s){
  drunkwalk<-as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=s,nrow=4^s-1))
  is.self.avoiding<-vector(mode="logical",length=4^s-1)
  for(i in 0:4^s-1){
      a<-convers(i,4)
      drunkwalk[i,]<-a
      if((!checkbacktrace(a))&&(!anyDuplicated(coords(a))))
        is.self.avoiding(i)<-TRUE
  }
  lim<-sum(is.self.avoiding)
  sarw<-as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=s,nrow=lim))
  ctr<-0
  for(i in 0:4^s-1){
    if(is.self.avoiding(i)){
        sarw[ctr,]<-drunkwalk[i,]
        ctr++
    } #error is pointing to this bracket
  }
  return(sarw)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

R does not support the `++` operator. Hence why the closing `}` is unexpected.

```
ctr = ctr + 1
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

R does not have increment and decrement operators. Instead of `ctr++`, you should use `ctr <- ctr + 1`.